# carrierwave heroku - keep getting error msg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am using rails 3.2.1, carrierwave 0.5.8, fog 1.1.2, rmagick 2.13.1.

I am trying to upload pictures of products onto an amazon s3, but i keep getting this error message no matter what permutation of the carrierwave.rb initializer file I find on the web (and I think I've tried them all), none seems to work.  Nothing is uploaded to my S3 bucket either.  I get the same error msg for the other versions I've tried.  I think it may be something in my controller, but not sure what could trip it. PLEASE HELP!

**error msg from heroku log:**

```
2012-03-05T06:35:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:40:in `update'
2012-03-05T06:35:18+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError (Missing required arguments:   aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key):
2012-03-05T06:35:18+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /products/3] invalidate, pass
```

**carrierwave initializer**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
 if Rails.env.production?
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_credentials = {
  :provider              => 'AWS',
  :aws_access_key_id     => 'access_key',
  :aws_secret_access_key => 'secret_access_key',
  :region                => 'us-east-1'
  }


 config.fog_directory  = 'bucket_name'
 config.fog_public     = true                                   
 config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000'}  

 else
  #for development and testing locally
  config.storage = :file
  config.enable_processing = false
 end
end
```

**image_uploader**

```
include CarrierWave::RMagick
  def store_dir
   "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb_pic do
   process :resize_to_limit => [170, 170]
  end
end
```

**controller**

```
  def create
   @all_categories = get_all_categories
   checked_categories = get_categories_from(params[:categories])
   removed_categories = @all_categories - checked_categories
   @product = Product.new(params[:product])
   if @product.save
    checked_categories.each {|cat| @product.categories << cat if !@product.categories.include?(cat)}
    removed_categories.each {|cat| @product.categories.delete(cat) if @product.categories.include?(cat)}
    redirect_to(:action => 'list')
  else
   render "new"
  end
end
```

This is what I see when I checked the heroku config

```
DATABASE_URL        => .....
GEM_PATH            => vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
LANG                => en_US.UTF-8
PATH                => bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
RACK_ENV            => production
RAILS_ENV           => production
S3_BUCKET           => bucket_name
S3_KEY              => access_key
S3_SECRET           => secret_access_key
SHARED_DATABASE_URL => .....
```

I've spent a good two days on this already and nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several issues wrong with my code.  I needed to change `config.fog_public` to false (per Amazon) and there was an issue with the fog gem from my end.  Apparently it wasn't transferring the information.  I had to manually add the info via these two lines:

`compute = Fog::Compute.new(:provider => 'AWS', :aws_access_key_id => ACCESS_KEY_ID, :aws_secret_access_key => SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)`

and

`storage = Fog::Storage.new(:provider => 'AWS', :aws_access_key_id => ACCESS_KEY_ID, :aws_secret_access_key => SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)`

After that, everything worked.  Also, make sure to put it in a string format because rails doesn't recognize anything starting in cap letters as a string unless made explicit.

Comment: I'm having similar trouble with carrierwave, aws and heroku deployment.  Works find locally but can't upload on deployment.  Could you please edit and add above exactly what your `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb` file looks like?  That might just get my app going.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the `if Rails.env.production?`.

If you're doing it right, you should be using [environment variables to store your credentials](http://www.12factor.net/config), and you should also be [matching your dev, test and productions environments](http://www.12factor.net/dev-prod-parity) in terms of functionality (Bucket name should also probably be a config var)

Comment: I've tried that as well and it's still not working.  I get the same error.  I even added `use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/uploads'], :root => 'tmp'` to my config.ru file and defined cache_dir in my uploader file and nothing works.  I still get the same error every time